# Proper way to define the schema for 'CustomDictionary.xml' in Visual Studio (2013)?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xsd, code-analysis

I'm making use of a custom dictionary ([`CustomDictionary.xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-customize-the-code-analysis-dictionary?view=vs-2017)) for Code Analysis, and it is working like it should. But, I keep getting warnings that indicate to me that the XML file is not defining its XSD schema location properly:

[image: CustomDictionary.xml warnings]

I found the XSD (`CustomDictionary.xsd`) on my machine, and I specified the scheme of its URI as type `file`:

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%2012.0/Team%20Tools/Static%20Analysis%20Tools/Schemas/CustomDictionary.xsd
```

With this URI, Chrome is able to locate the XSD file just fine. That said, how do I properly reference `CustomDictionary.xsd` from within `CustomDictionary.xml`?

What I have found so far indicates that the following *should* work, but it is not:

```
<Dictionary
  xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/ file:/.../CustomDictionary.xsd">
```

(Note that I have truncated the path to `CustomDictionary.xsd` for clarity.)

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Add `CustomDictionary.xsd` into your project. And in your XML file, `CustomDictionary.xml`, add the `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attributes to the `Dictionary` element as follows:

```
<Dictionary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CustomDictionary.xsd">
```