# Schema errors when validating 'CustomDictionary.xml' via 'CustomDictionary.xsd' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, validation, xsd, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I am now getting IntelliSense validation in Visual Studio when I edit `CustomDictionary.xml` by incorporating a reference to `CustomDictionary.xsd` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28394657/1497596). However, I am getting validation errors in Microsoft's default `CustomDictionary.xml` which I did not expect. For example, for this entry:

```xml
<Term PreferredAlternate="EnterpriseServices">complus</Term>
```

...I am seeing the error:

> The element cannot contain text. Content model is empty.

(Note that I am seeing a blue squiggled line beneath the word `complus`.) This suggests that there is a problem with the `CustomDictionary.xsd` schema file. Note that I obtained my copy of the schema file from this location within my Visual Studio 2017 installation:

```xml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team Tools\
    Static Analysis Tools\Schemas\CustomDictionary.xsd
```

And that the default `CustomDictionary.xml` can be found here:

```xml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team Tools\
    Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\CustomDictionary.xml
```

**Proposed remedy:** To get proper validation for `CustomDictionary.xml` in Visual Studio, it seems that changes need to be made to `CustomDictionary.xsd`. Can anyone confirm this?

---

**Additional comment:** I find it notable that these files have not changed since it least Visual Studio 2013. Here are their locations:

```xml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\
    Static Analysis Tools\Schemas\CustomDictionary.xsd

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\
    Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\CustomDictionary.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched my question and made changes to `CustomDictionary.xsd` that resolved the IntelliSense validation errors that I had been seeing. Here are those changes:

**Before:**

```xml
<xs:attribute name="PreferredAlternate" type="xs:string" use="required" />

<xs:attribute name="CompoundAlternate" type="xs:string" use="required" />
```

**After:**

```xml
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="PreferredAlternate" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>

<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="CompoundAlternate" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
```

Comment: Hi David, we are so glad to hear that your issue is solved, thanks for your sharing. Please mark your reply as answer when you have free time, that will help others to easier search this helpful information, thanks in advance.